# CakePHP - Inflection Configuration

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a table `product_media` and cake is not inflecting `media` to `medium`.

I have added the following to `app/Config/bootstrap.php`:

```
Inflector::rules('singular', array('irregular' => array('media' => 'medium')));
```

This works fine for a table named `media` but does not work for my table named `product_media`.

Anyone know why?

Comment: can you list your model names and table names?

Comment: (and specify what you mean "does not work")?

Comment: When I say 'does not work' I mean the word does not get inflected.

Answer (score 0):

It probably matches the whole word only if no specific rules are given. Try this:

```
Inflector::rules(
    'singular', 
    array(
        'rules' => array( 
            '/(.*)media$/i' => '\1medium' 
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   Inflector::rules('uninflected', array('media', 'medium'));
```

or

```
 Inflector::rules('uninflected' => array('singulars'),
'irregular' => array('media' => 'medium')
```